# ArcPy spatial join script error

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, modelbuilder, spatial-join, error-000725

I made a model for spatial join and it is working properly but when I export as script and run in ArcPy it gave me error in spatial join. Here is the code

```py
import arcpy

# Script arguments
Houses = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
if Houses == '#' or not Houses:
    Houses = "Houses.shp" # provide a default value if unspecified

Sub_blocks = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
if Sub_blocks == '#' or not Sub_blocks:
    Sub_blocks = "Sub_blocks.shp" # provide a default value if unspecified

Houses_sub_blocks_shp = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
if Houses_sub_blocks_shp == '#' or not Houses_sub_blocks_shp:
    Houses_sub_blocks_shp = "E:\\MS\\2nd Semester\\python\\Data\\New data\\Houses_sub_blocks.shp" # provide a default value if unspecified

alternatives = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
if alternatives == '#' or not alternatives:
    alternatives = "alternatives" # provide a default value if unspecified

C1_houses = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
if C1_houses == '#' or not C1_houses:
    C1_houses = "alternatives" # provide a default value if unspecified

# Local variables:

# Process: Spatial Join
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(Sub_blocks, Houses, Houses_sub_blocks_shp)

# Process: Join Field
arcpy.JoinField_management(alternatives, "FID", Houses_sub_blocks_shp, "FID", "Join_Count")
```

and the error is

[image: Error message]

Comment: It says that the output already exists, either change the output name, delete it or start your script with arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z0000004s000000 please **do not use FID as a join field** feature ids are not static, object ids are, create a new field and populate it with a unique number and join using that or one day it will come back to bite you.

Comment: @MichaelStimson i have correct the 3 errors but spatial join error is still un-solved

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to include the error as *text*. Images are not legible on all devices and cannot be searched by others.

Comment: with some tools, blank spaces still cause errors. Try with a path without blank spaces.

Comment: How did you fix the errors? As @Vince said please edit your question with your updated code and the associated error message as text, formatted as code for readability, start with *Traceback* and finish with the line beginning *Failed to execute*.